# How to make an icon/span selectable by pressing Tab key?

Tags: html, angular, tabs, focus

I have two input boxes and the users enter their credentials, then clicking on the span that invokes the authentication process. It works great on a phone but for a laptop/desktop, I've been informed that they prefer to use <kbd>Tab</kbd> to jump between the three controls.

At the moment, only the input boxes are tabbable to (focusable, selectable?) and I wonder if I can easy make the span element reachable by pressing tab key. I don't want to create a whole logic for detecting children etc. as it would be way too complicated and unmotivated.

```
<span class="nav-item">
  <input [(ngModel)]="userName">
</span>
<span class="nav-item">
  <input [(ngModel)]=password>
</span>
<span class="nav-item"
      (click)="authenticate()">
  <fa-icon [icon]="faSignInAlt"></fa-icon>
</span>
```

I've googled it but got little relevant hits. The best was to change span into a button and format it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can add tabindex to it.

```
<span class="nav-item">
  <input [(ngModel)]="userName">
</span>
<span class="nav-item">
  <input [(ngModel)]=password>
</span>
<span class="nav-item"
      (click)="authenticate()" tabindex="0">
  <fa-icon [icon]="faSignInAlt"></fa-icon>
</span>
```

Comment: It does work as to marking the component with the border so it's definitely focusable. However, I noticed that pressing enter or space doesn't invoke the clicky'ness of it, anyway. Suggestions?

Comment: are you sure? i just tried it and i can press enter

Comment: It seems to not work in my case - I had to add `(keyup)` to handle that. Perhaps it's got to do with different Angular versions? I tried that in Angular 6 in Chrome...

Answer (score 0):

Thank you DonkeyBanana.
With your idea, I was able to focus in the object (in my case an icon). Then, I had the same problem with the invoice property as Shanks says.
I was able to solve it with en EventListener:

```
submit.addEventListener("keydown", async (e) => {
    if (e.key=="Enter" || e.key=="Space") funcionSubmit(e);
});
```